# Bash: effect of running `set -i`?

Tags: bash

Today I was reading through the documentation of `set`, when I realised that my flags variable (`$-`) contained a flag undocumented on the help page (`help set`) and on [GNU.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html): `i`.
After some time I managed to find [this page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html) which states that `i` stands for *interactive*.
The first thing I then tried, of course, was to turn it off.
After running `set +i`, `$-` no longer contained an `i`, but apart from that, everything was apparently still working as always.
Likewise, putting `set -i` in a script file had no apparent effect when running it.

So, my question: Does putting `set -i`/`set +i` in a script or running it on the command line actually have any effect other than modifying the `$-` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the only consequence of using `set -i` or `set +i` on the command-line once the shell has initialized is to change the value of `$-`. The `-i` option can be used meaningfully only when invoking `bash` to create a shell, in which case it will force the shell to be interactive.

A quick examination of the bash source shows that interactive checks during execution refer to the global variable `interactive`, which is set during the initialization sequence and then not modified. Only `set [+-]i` and `$-` use the `forced_interactive` global. (`interactive` will be set to true if `forced_interactive` is set or otherwise as described in `man bash`.)

Answer (score 0):

bash-1.14.7-14 has documentiation for the -i option in the man page.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1129

```
   -i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```

An interactive shell reads commands from user input on a tty. Among other things, such a shell reads startup files on activation, displays a prompt, and enables job control by default. The user can interact with the shell. A shell running a script is always a non-interactive shell.

Further information here:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43385/what-do-you-mean-by-interactive-shell

Addition: More links

A really good answer about non-login shells

https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells

The bash manual on interactive shells

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior

Comment: I get that, but whether a shell is interactive or not depends only on how it is started, right? So, does running `set +i` on the command line (when the shell is already running) actually do anything, apart from modifying `$-`?

Comment: The interactive state is only acted upon during shell initialization, so changing it at the command line will do nothing to the remainder of your session.